# How can I use imported .PSD files in GWT-Designer?

Tags: gwt, user-interface, import, psd, gwt-designer

I have various .PSD files that compose an interface. I am trying to learn GWT and GWT-Designer. Can anybody point me to a way to import those files with GWT-Designer so that I may code the interface ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

GWT-Designer doesn't import PSD files directly. I would look at the various panels and widgets available in GWT Designer and try to map those to the elements in your image file. Since you're learning, start with something simple and move up from there.